# Is pair $(m, -m)$ which $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $\{(m, -m)\mid m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

What i know about isomorphic is, simply it is a bijective homomorphism.

How one can define isomorphism map $\phi$ in above case?

Comment: What do you mean by $(m, -m)$? Is it an interval of $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb R$? Is it an element of $\Bbb Z\times Z$?

Comment: @Arthur: I feel he meant the second one.

Comment: @Arthur, Babak is right i $(m,-m)$ is a element of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is ! Just take $$\varphi: \mathbb Z\longrightarrow M$$
defined by $$\varphi(m)= (m,-m).$$

The surjectivity is obvious. For the injectivity, it's easy to prove that $\ker \varphi=\{0\}.$

Comment: great, i see the point

Answer (score 1):

The pair $(m, -m)$ is an **element** of $\mathbb Z^2$

$\mathbb Z$ is a **set**, and with the operation $+$ it is a **group**.

---

Speaking about homomorphisms between the two makes very little sensem because $(m, -m)$ is not a group (because even though technically, it is a set of two elements, you haven't defined an operation on it).

---

What I feel you are **really** trying to ask is the following question:

> Is the set $\{(m, -m)| m\in\mathbb Z\}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$?

In which case the answer is still *unclear*, because you **still** haven't defined an operation. Now, if the operation is $$(m, -m) + (n, -n) = (m+n, -(m+n)),$$

then **yes**, the two groups are isomorphic, and one possible isomorphism is ***the most obvious mapping you can possibly think of***.

Comment: oh i see, i should be more precise to asking some question.